# Oracle procedure can be terminated if the app is forced to stop?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

when the app ( which is executing Oracle procedure by oracle api )

is terminated by accident ( that is ora session is opened normally but not colsed ) ,

the procedure being excuted will be stop right now or continue excuting until completed ?

Answer (score 3):

The query will continue executing until the call is completed and it tries to communicate with the client again, when it will probably find the client gone and rollback any uncommitted transaction.

I believe you have to kill off the session running the query, assuming there's only one.  It's very unlikely an application would provide this functionality.

Comment: I'd refine "until completed" to be "until the call is completed and it tries to communicate with the client again, when it will probably find the client gone and rollback any uncommitted transaction".